# Were high level stats ever released for Lusiphur?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am currently running a Forgotten Realms campaign and would like to shake up my players with a Lusiphur ([*Poison Elves*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_Elves)) based NPC. Does anyone know if Drew Hayes ever published Luse's high level D&D stats?

Answer (score 3):

## [Hayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drew_Hayes) probably didn't write up [Lusipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_Elves) for any role-playing game

I'm working from memory, but I think Lusipher, while based on an *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition* character, had already outgrown that role-playing game character by the time Hayes started drawing and writing about him in [*Poison Elves*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_Elves) (né *I, Lusipher*) in 1991. Further, I think a [Starting Note](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157989092X) or an answer to a letter explained  that, by the time he started self-publishing, Hayes had stopped gaming, choosing to focus on *Poison Elves* and raising his daughter.<sup>1</sup>

Ben Djarum in a 2013 *Codex Apocrypha* [blog entry](http://codexapocrypha.blogspot.com/2013/01/poison-elves.html) says that

> During the height of d20 mania [c. 2000-03] someone asked [Hayes] in a letter if had ever thought of writing a *Poison Elves* RPG. Drew declined, but said that if there was going to be one, he'd want it to run on the old *[Runequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuneQuest)* [link added] system....

If absolutely desperate, you could hunt down the seemingly-unavailable-except-on-*EBay* *Poison Elves Encyclopedia* CD-ROM, but, I doubt it will have what you want. (I'd provide more information about this item, but I've torn up my house and can't find mine, and the Web holds only scant details about the *Encyclopedia*.)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> As an aside I remember reading that George R. R. Martin said that writing about characters that you also role-play is too hard, better to do one or the other. He'd know: his [*Superworld*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superworld) campaign became the anthology series [*Wild Cards*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Cards).